# Regarding retain count

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ag", @"sdfg", @"dgh", nil] retain];
NSArray *newArr = [[arr mutableCopy] retain];
[arr release];
[newArr release];
newArr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"sdfdhs"];
```

What will retain count after each line? Please explain this to me. Thanking You...

Comment: Have a look at http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: Well see it for yourself with instruments.

Comment: Are you interviewing us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retain counts are pretty much useless, see http://whentouseretaincounts.com for details of why.

However, I added calls to `retainCount` to your code and ran the following:

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ag", @"sdfg", @"dgh", nil] retain];
NSLog(@"%ld", [arr retainCount]);

NSArray *newArr = [[arr mutableCopy] retain];
NSLog(@"%ld", [newArr retainCount]);

[arr release];
NSLog(@"%ld", [arr retainCount]);

[newArr release];
NSLog(@"%ld", [newArr retainCount]);

newArr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"sdfdhs"];
NSLog(@"%ld", [newArr retainCount]);
```

and got the following results:

```
2013-01-24 15:45:56.840 Untitled 2[96774:707] 2 
2013-01-24 15:45:56.842 Untitled 2[96774:707] 2 
2013-01-24 15:45:56.842 Untitled 2[96774:707] 1 
2013-01-24 15:45:56.843 Untitled 2[96774:707] 1 
2013-01-24 15:45:56.843 Untitled 2[96774:707] 1
```

The first result is `2` not `1` because the return value from `arrayWithObjects` has been autoreleased but hasn't actually been released yet because the autorelease pool has not been flushed yet (this usually happens in the event loop).

The second result is `2` because the `mutableCopy` returned a retained object and we are `retain`ing it again.

The third result is `1` because we release `arr` which had a retain count of `2`.  Still haven't flushed the autorelease pool.

The fourth result is `1` because we released `newArr` which had a retain count of `2`.

The final result is `1` because we leaked the contents of `newArr` and assigned a new autoreleased array to the variable.  The retain count of `1` is the not yet autoreleased count.

However, retain counts should not be trusted.  Learn the memory management rules (whether you are using ARC or not).